# How to make player restrict of boundries only left right not up and down in phaser js game?

Tags: phaser-framework

How to make player restrict  of boundries only left right not up and down in phaser js game?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the custom world bounds, with the function `this.physics.world.setBounds(...)`.
[Here a link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.World.html).

So, you just would have to put this line, into your code:

```
`this.physics.world.setBounds(0, 0, widthOfTheGame, heightOfTheGame, true, true, false, true);`.
```

in the `create` function.

> following the documenttation `setBounds(x, y, width, height [, checkLeft] [, checkRight] [, checkUp] [, checkDown])`

The third `false` is for the *world-bounds-top*, and so no colliding should occure.